# Android RemoteViews addView only first view showing

Tags: android, widget

I've seen several posts about this, but found no answers to the issue that I'm experiencing. I'm dynamically filling a LinearLayout in a homescreen widget with RelativeLayout views, but only the first child view is displaying. Debugging shows that multiple views are being created and added, but they don't appear. Here's the code:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
Cursor statuses_styles = getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(Statuses_styles.CONTENT_URI, widget), new String[]{...}, null, null, Statuses_styles.CREATED + " DESC LIMIT " + page + ",-1");
Log.d(TAG,"statuses count:"+statuses_styles.getCount());
if (statuses_styles.moveToFirst()) {
    int count_status = 0;
    views.removeAllViews(R.id.messages);
    while (!statuses_styles.isAfterLast() && (count_status < 16)) {
        RemoteViews itemView;
        itemView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_item);
        itemView.setTextViewText(R.id.message, statuses_styles.getString(1));
        itemView.setFloat(R.id.message, "setTextSize", friend_textsize);
        Log.d(TAG,"add view:"+statuses_styles.getString(1));
        views.addView(R.id.messages, itemView);
        count_status++;
        statuses_styles.moveToNext();
    }
}
statuses_styles.close();
mgr.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
```

The widget is simply a LinearLayout with the id of "messages". It's set to fill_parent for width and height and has orienation set to vertical.

The widget item is a relative layout containing some text and image views.

The widget is a 4x4.

Any ideas why none of the other views are appearing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A child of the view being added had the attribute layout_alignParentBottom="true", which caused it to fill the whole parent, blocking any additional children. Removing the attribute allowed the other children to appear.

Comment: I faced a similar issue, where the LinearLayout, that contained to view that should be added had the attribute layout_height="match_parent", resulting in the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just if anyone is reading this and is facing the problem of inflating a bunch of views into a linear layout, which is part of a xml somewhere else and 
only sees the first inflated layout, but does not know why.

My fault was, that I created a View class extending LinearLayout, but 
did not set the orientation to vertical inside of the xml, where I 
actually used the view - so the views where added, but horiztonal.

Hope, this helps anyone.

Example:

```
myLayout.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
```